# Enable header for first page only using pdfkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have added header using:
%meta{:name => 'pdfkit-header_html', :content => pdf_header_url}

But I need header only on first page and not on the other pages.
Also, I need different header_spacing on the first page and other pages.
Please, suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

#### pdf.html

`%html
  %head
    %meta{:name => 'pdfkit-header_html', :content => pdf_header_url }`

Now in the pdf_header action the params[:page] will be available

`def pdf_header
   if params[:page] == 1
     render 'pdf_header'
   else
     render nothing: true
   end
end`